# Bulk Tag Bigquery columns with python & Google Cloud Datacatalog

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Is there a way to bulk tag bigquery tables with python google.cloud.datacatalog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to take a look at sample code which uses the python `google.cloud.datacatalog` client library, I've put together a utilities open source script, that creates bulk Tags using a CSV as source. If you want to use a different source, you may use this script as reference, hope it helps.

[create bulk tags from csv](https://github.com/mesmacosta/datacatalog-util#2-load-tags-from-csv-file)

Comment: Thank you! I've managed to bulk tag all tables, now I'll find a way to look up in every table if a specific column has personal info and tag this column individually, (we have more than 150 tables).

Comment: If your use case is tagging all your Big Query Tables (150 tables or more), there's a community tutorial that shows how to do that using DLP, please take a look at it and let me know if it helps you.

[create PII tags for all your Big Query Tables](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/dlp-to-datacatalog-tags)

Comment: Thank you!, It is very useful, but I'll need to work with specific columns. I was thinking about something like:                                                                             
    `table_entry = datacatalog.lookup_entry(linked_resource=resource_name)`
    `tag = datacatalog_v1beta1.types.Tag()`
    `tag.template = tag_template.name`
    `tag.fields['pii_inside'].bool_value = True`
    `tag.fields['pii_info'].enum_value.display_name = tag_field_value`
    `tag = datacatalog.create_tag(parent=table_entry.name, tag=tag)`
    `tag.column = column_name`

Comment: I see, in that case the same bulk tags CSV script I pointed, allows you to tag columns, all you gotta do is fill the column name. Otherwise the Python snippet in your comment should work.

Comment: Thank you @mesmacosta! The python snippet worked fine, but it worked just fine for entry.tables but not for entry.tables.views, I didn't find anything on the code I can adjust to tag the views also. Do you know if this is normal?

Comment: Data Catalog uses the **resource_name** to attach the **tag**, you just have to do a lookup_entry using the view resource name, if your provide that value you will use the same code snippet.
If this does not work for you, please elaborate what you mean by **entry.tables.views**

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose you may consider using `DataCatalogClient()` method which is included in [google.cloud.datacatalog_v1](https://googleapis.dev/python/datacatalog/latest/gapic/v1/api.html) class as a part of [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-datacatalog/) Python `google-cloud-datacatalog` package leveraging *Google Cloud Data Catalog API* service.

- By the first, you have to enable Data Catalog and BigQuery [APIs](https://cloud.google.com/data-catalog/docs/quickstart-tagging#create_a_tag_template_and_attach_the_tag_to_your_table)
  in your project;
- [Install](https://cloud.google.com/data-catalog/docs/reference/libraries#installing_the_client_library) Python Cloud Client Libraries for the Data Catalog API:

  `pip install --upgrade google-cloud-datacatalog`
- Set up [authentication](https://cloud.google.com/data-catalog/docs/reference/libraries#setting_up_authentication), exporting
  `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable holding JSON
  file that contains your service account key:

  `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/home/user/Downloads/[FILE_NAME].json"`
- Refer to [this](https://cloud.google.com/data-catalog/docs/quickstart-tagging#create_a_tag_template_and_attach_the_tag_to_your_table) example from official documentation that
  intelligibly reflects a way creating Data catalog tag template,
  attaching appropriate tag fields to the target Bigquery table using
  [create_tag_template()](https://googleapis.dev/python/datacatalog/latest/_modules/google/cloud/datacatalog_v1/gapic/data_catalog_client.html#DataCatalogClient.create_tag_template) function.

Having any doubts feel free to extend you initial question or add a comment below this answer, thus we can address particular use case according to your needs.